# Fread segfault when reading struct from file

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, fread

I'm almost done with my minesweeper game in C.
currently i'm trying to implement a savegame functionality.
After the player is asked for his name, the game checks, if there is a file with his name.
If yes, it is attempted to load the file, and restore the game struct.

I have extended the struct a bit, it looks like this:

```c
typedef struct GAMEOBJECT {
  gamestate STATE;  ///< the current State of the game. see GAMESTATE.
  uint8_t width;    ///< width of the game board.
  uint8_t height;   ///< height of the game board.
  int  mines;       ///< the amount of mines places on the game board.
  size_t elements;  ///< total amount of cells (width*height).
  cell *cells;      ///< pointer to the start of the cell pointer array.
  player player;    ///< Structure to store Player Data;
  status status;    ///< Structure to store game infos;
} gameObject;
```

there are 3 other structs used inside of this construct:

```c
typedef struct GAMES{
  int total;
  int won;
  int lost;
  int cells;
} games;

typedef struct STATUS{
  int moves;
  int flagged;
  int revealed;
} status;

typedef struct PLAYER {
  char name[20];
  games games;
} player;
```

Question:
- Are structs inside the GameObject Structs are being saved as well, when attempting to write the GameObject struct to a file? (i know for Cells* that i have to do it seperately, as this is only a pointer to a different struct.

The load functions boiled down to essentials:

```c
savegameState loadGame(gameObject *Minesweeper, char *player){
        FILE *savegame = fopen(savegameName,"rb");
[...]
            //loading Gameboard from file to memory...
            size_t items_board = fread (Minesweeper, sizeof(gameObject), 1, savegame);
            //allocating memory for the Cells...
            Minesweeper->cells = (cell*)calloc(Minesweeper->elements,sizeof(cell));
            //loading cells from file to memory...           
            size_t items_cells = fread (Minesweeper->cells, sizeof(cell), Minesweeper->elements, savegame);

[...]
errorhandling
```

save Function:

```c
savegameState saveGame(gameObject *Minesweeper, char *player){
[...]
        FILE *savegame = fopen(savegameName,"r+b");
[...]
        size_t items_board = fwrite (&Minesweeper, sizeof(gameObject), 1, savegame); 
        size_t items_cells = fwrite (&Minesweeper->cells, sizeof(cell), Minesweeper->elements, savegame);

[...] errorhandling
```

tried to comment out the save for cell area, but still segfaulting...

maybe important, the init functions for the main GameObject:

```c
  // Allocating memory for the board struct.
  gameObject *Minesweeper = (gameObject *)calloc(1,sizeof(gameObject));

  //Initing Board Parameters
  Minesweeper->width = width;
  Minesweeper->height = height;
  Minesweeper->elements = height*width;
  Minesweeper->mines = mineCount;
  Minesweeper->STATE=INIT;
  strcpy(Minesweeper->player.name,player);
  Minesweeper->cells = (cell*)calloc(Minesweeper->elements,sizeof(cell));

  if (!fromFile){
    //placing mines and getting neighboring mines.
    placeMines(Minesweeper,mineCount);
    getNeighborMines(Minesweeper); 
    revealFirst(Minesweeper);
  } else {
    Minesweeper->STATE = RESTORE;
  }

  //return struct
  return Minesweeper;
}
```

If the savegame is detected, this init function gets called with basic params (10x10 matrix, 5 mines) to be able to init the Object.

(Or should i only init the GameObject? And dont care about the Cells Pointer?)

Comment: `realloc(Minesweeper->cells` is an invalid pointer: you read `cells` from the file.

Comment: hi, in the initialize function of the game, i already allocate space for this area. As i have to init the board, before loading the savegame, i use a "fixed" value (10x10 matrix). My attempt is to enlarge the memory, after the file is loaded, and correct dimensions of the previous gamesession (savegame) is restored. After this, i want to write the cell structure back from file to memory.

Comment: hi, you don't seem to understand what you are doing: you first do `fread (&Minesweeper` and then `Minesweeper->cells=realloc(` but the `fread` has _overwritten_ the `cells` field, so you have lost anything you did in your initialization and end up with an _invalid pointer_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Then the realloc does not make any sense obviously.

Comment: I have edited the function for loading the game above. First, the board gets loaded, then memory allocated (not by realloc), then the cells read from file.

Comment: I removed the & in fread statement. Now it seems to work.